# Android Studios retrieve an href that is dynamicaly loaded with javascript

Tags: javascript, android

Looking for ideas on the subject of retrieving dynamically created data from a web site through an Android application using java.
Currently scraping with Jsoup and is fine for what i need it for. I am however trying to make use of the sites search bar in order to return a page link. This page link is loaded in via javascript which I know Jsoup cannot read.
Have been unable to make use of selenium and HTMLUnit.
Was also thinking androids webView may be the answer but havent found a working way with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special version of HtmlUnit for Android.

https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android

Please open an issue if it does not work and I will try to help.